# Unit test cases in pimcore, getting error while executing test cases

Tags: php, symfony, pimcore

pimcore v 6.6

im trying to unit test by codeception, i have installed codception and tests/ folder created under my project directory. But when im calling the service function getting below error

Error attached

**[PHPUnit\Framework\Exception] Use of undefined constant PIMCORE_PROJECT_ROOT - assumed ‘PIMCORE_PROJECT_ROOT’ (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)

src/GenericBundle/Service/PdfImportService.php:31**

File name for test is PdfImportServiceTest.php

```
public function testGetFilesArray() { 
    $pdfService = new PdfImportService(); 
    $this->assertFalse($pdfService->getFilesArray()); 
}
```

I have added bootstrap.php file inside tests/ path

code is here

// tests/bootstrap.php

```
include “./vendor/autoload.php”;

\Pimcore\Bootstrap::setProjectRoot(); 
\Pimcore\Bootstrap::bootstrap();
```

===================================================

added another file named codeception.dist.yml

```
namespace: Tests support_namespace: 
           Support actor_suffix: Tester 
paths: 
    tests: . 
    output: ./_output 
    data: ./Support/Data 
    support: ./Support 
    envs: ./_envs 
settings: 
    bootstrap: _bootstrap.php 
    colors: true 
params: - env 
extensions: 
    enabled: - Codeception\Extension\RunFailed
```

=============================================================
also i have added _bootstrap.php && codeception.yml file inside tests/ as per in the pimcore doc

when im executing this test case, its calling constructor of actual service file and there we have defined constant path for the file, but this test case is not working. Actual function from the backend is working

[image]
[image]

in some services im getting get container null error… Please check the link for error.

I followed pimcore unit testing document + symfony documnet + codception document. But it didnt work for me. Im stuck with this from 3 days.

Please let me know how to resolve it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Base on error, are you sure you define the ```PIMCORE_PROJECT_ROOT``` constant manually in your ```bootstrap.php```? It should looks like ```define('PIMCORE_PROJECT_ROOT', __DIR__);```

Comment: @KeyboardCorporation, thanks for the response. As i read in the pimcore document, its saying that you just have to add path and code given in the document. So it will load the file from the vendor and access.. So in my bootstrap.php file there is no code defined for constant, as mentioned code above

Comment: Can't you just try to define it? Which part on the documentation is it? Please share, as I read [here](https://pimcore.com/docs/pimcore/10.6/Development_Documentation/Development_Tools_and_Details/Testing/Application_Testing.html), you need to define it.

Comment: As you can see in the same document which u shared, its mentioned only to add below code in bootstrap.php
// tests/bootstrap.php

include "../../vendor/autoload.php";

\Pimcore\Bootstrap::setProjectRoot();
\Pimcore\Bootstrap::bootstrap();

Comment: also i tried to define the constant, but im getting below error => 

PHP Warning:  Class 'PHPUnit\Framework\Assert' not found in /vendor/codeception/phpunit-wrapper/src/shim.php on line 7

PHP Warning:  Class 'PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase' not found in /vendor/codeception/phpunit-wrapper/src/shim.php on line 11

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase' not found in vendor/codeception/codeception/src/Codeception/Test/Unit.php:14

Comment: Have you try to [mock](https://i.imgur.com/tNepltE.png) the service container and inject it into the service?

Comment: @KeyboardCorporation, Thanks for the suggestion. But i added dependency service container. But still same error exists => PHP Warning: Class 'PHPUnit\Framework\Assert' not found in /vendor/codeception/phpunit-wrapper/src/shim.php on line 7 PHP Warning: Class 'PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase' not found in /vendor/codeception/phpunit-wrapper/src/shim.php on line 11 PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase' not found in vendor/codeception/codeception/src/Codeception/Test/Unit.php:14